# Сервер на no-ip

Tags: c#, сервер

Написал сервер и клиент на C#, использую стандартный `HttpListener`, по *localhost* работает все в порядке, но никак не могу выдвинуть его в интернет.

зарегистрировался в *no-ip*, скачал *DUC* и включил его, пытаюсь запустить его на таком адресе:

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://" + "выданный DUC адрес " + ":801/");
```

но получаю ошибку:

> httplistenerexeption - "Сетевая папка недоступна.".

Comment: скорее всего Вы сидите за роутером/натом, а порты не пробросили.

Comment: подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Решение данной задачи сильно зависит от Вашей текущей конфигурации - наличия роутеров, их моделей,  особеностей провайдера. Без знания структуры сети давать какие то советы не имеет смысла.

Comment: Роутер есть, TP Link, DDNS от no-ip там включил. Ну как бы направить можете, или ссылку дать где почитать, где и как обычно порты перебрасываются?

Comment: Вот в картинках http://forum.tp-linkru.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9

Comment: теперь пишет Bad Request (Invalid host), в чем проблема, подскажете?

Comment: А это уже похоже проблема Вашего сервера и к настройке роутера не имеет отношения. Хотя есть много различных вариантов. 

Я бы для начала поднял апач или любой другой вебсервер (можно на питоне в одну строку) и проверил, что все пробрасывается правильно.

Comment: Но локально же все работает(в пределах сети роутера), сервер рабочий, что может быть?
поесть извне уже видит что сервер есть, прогресс, но теперь это, я тоже бы так подумал, но так бы он и локально не работал.